# jQuery to get value of div and display to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the value of a div class and then use that value in another div by appending it somehow.

So say I click on product-item small below. I want **item 1** to display in the p class of "added-item"

https://jsfiddle.net/jmy8fqqx/

```
<a href="#" class="purchase"><span class="product-item small">item 1</span></a>
<a href="#" class="purchase"><span class="product-item medium">item 2</span></a>
<a href="#" class="purchase"><span class="product-item big">item 3</span></a>


<div class="bought">
  <p class="added-item">
      <!-- content will be loaded using jQuery - according to the selected item -->
  </p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
  $( ".purchase" ).click(function() {

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. Please next time give some code you have tried.

```
$( ".purchase" ).click(function() {
    var item = $(this).find('span').html();
    $('p.added-item').html(item);
});
```